# unable to pull an https url within R

Tags: r, https, rcurl

I need to get a https get request using RCurl as follows:

```
url<-c("https://example.com")

x<-getURL(url)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to host
```

I can definetely connect to internet from my R session since I can connect to cran to install R packages. This url that I am connecting does not require username/password since there is a key within the url. I can manually get to this url with the browswer. Can anybody tell me what might be wrong here?

Comment: try: `url<-c("http://example.com")`

Comment: getURL(url) still giving me that error. But download.file worked this time after changing it to http.

Comment: You could answer your own question below then.

Answer (score 2):

changed the url from https to http call and it worked for me:

```
url<-c("http:/example.com")
download.file(url, destfile="test.xml")
```

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer. Post it as a comment. (or in the question directly)